# For graduate admission, would 3-year bachelor’s program without thesis suffice in chemistry field?

Tags: graduate-admissions

I am a Thai graduate from a university in New Zealand with a 3-year Bachelor of Science (Chemistry) without having completed a thesis. Although I could have done my fourth year doing a thesis which is called “Bachelor Honours Degree” in New Zealand, my scholarship sponsor did not allow me.

I am now a research assistant at the research center in Thailand. I really wish to continue my career further in academia abroad since I feel more comfortable when studying or working in English. However, I found it difficult to apply for the international scholarship and admission for master’s or PhD program as the general requirement would be either having completed bachelor’s degree with practical components (I assumed this could be a thesis) or graduated with 2:1 honours degree equivalence such as in UK.

I tried to apply for master’s degree at one of the Northern Irish universities but got rejected since my academic qualification wasn’t enough and they required me to complete my fourth year with thesis.

I am wondering if there are any countries/universities that thesis would not be generally required for a graduate admission?

My employer suggested me to keep sending emails to many potential professors to see if I can be exempted from the requirement. Would that be possible?

Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score -1):

If you were eligible for a

> Bachelor Honours Degree (Chemistry)

at a New Zealand university, then you would probably also be eligible for the the same degree at most Australian universities.  Unlike the UK, "Honours" is a degree sort of like a masters.

New Zealand degrees are not widely known outside Australia and New Zealand.